# Handling PopUs in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

How to remove an alert that is not having any ok/Cancel button .It just have a link to which i will be redirected to and small cross button at top right of it.

example : An activity is pending with me . Every time i login to website it shows me an alert to complete the Activity . It is not having Ok or Cancel button.

`driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();`  is not working . Any suggestion ??

Given is the **Alert Pic**

[image]

Comment: If switchTo is not working then this is not a broswer alert, it is created through html. Use the inspect option and check it.

Comment: @tsarvesh Are you able to close/dismiss it manually?

Comment: @debanjan , Yes i am able to close it manually it is having a cross sign at top right side of it .On getting the Xpath of that 
"X" button i am getting this : "/html/body/div[14]/div/span"                       On finding element and using .click(); to close it is not Working .

Comment: If the _Alert/Popup_ is not having  _Ok/Cancel_ button I suppose it's volatile. Why don't you wait for the _Alert/Popup_ to disappear?

Comment: Post the relevant HTML, e.g. the HTML of the X button and maybe some surrounding HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try locating "X" in upper left corner with

```
driver.findElement(By....)).click();
```

maybe it should dismiss notification.

Comment: Tried the below code but it is not working  :                                                                                               Thread.sleep(2000L);
driver.switchTo().alert();
WebElement popup = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[14]/div/span"));
  popup.click();

Comment: This is not alert, so You probably shouldn't switch as alery, Does it maybe have some iFrame, or any kind of frame, so You probably then have to switch a frame not alert.